# complex numbers equation, find all z...

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

So i have to find all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ 
that solve these two equations(separately)

first:

$\bar{z}+z=i(\bar{z}-z)$

second:

$\bar{z}+z^n=i(\bar{z}-z^n), \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$

So basically, i think that first one is solved with just defining $z=a+bi$ and the second one with moivre formule, but i'm not sure.

(But i also want to know if it's possible to solve the second one after i solve the first, and try for few other $n$ and then prove with induction that it works, or is that wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bar{z} + z^n =i(\bar{z} - z^n ) \Longleftrightarrow (1-i) \bar{z} + (1+i)z^n =0 \Longleftrightarrow 2\bar{z} +2i z^n = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \bar{z} +iz^n =0\Longleftrightarrow |z|^2 +iz^{n+1} =0 \Longrightarrow (z^{n+1} \in i\mathbb{R}_+ \wedge ( n+1 =2 \vee |z|=1 )) $
Since the case $n=1 $ and $z^2 \in i\mathbb{R}_+ $ is trivial. We considel only the case $|z|=1$ i.e. $z=\cos \varphi +i\sin \varphi. $ Because $z^{n+1} \in i\mathbb{R}_+$ we get $$\cos (n+1)\varphi =0 $$ and $$\sin (n+1)\varphi \geqslant 0$$ thus $$\varphi =\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)} + \frac{2k\pi}{n+1} $$ hence $$z=\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)} + \frac{2k\pi}{n+1}\right) +i\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)} + \frac{2k\pi}{n+1}\right).$$

Comment: I've got another question @MotylaNogaTomkaMazura what does $i\mathbb{R}_+ $ mean?

Comment: $i\mathbb{R}_+ =\{ti :t\geqslant 0\}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $m\neq n$, we have two equations:
$$\begin{cases}
\bar{z}+z^{m}=i(\bar{z}-z^{m}) &  \\ 
\bar{z}+z^{n}=i(\bar{z}-z^{n}) &  
\end{cases}$$

Then we have,

$$z^{m}-z^{n}=i(z^{n}-z^{m})$$

If $z^{m}\neq z^{n}$, we have $-1 = i$, a contradiction.
Therefore $z^{m}=z^{n}, \forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Take $m=1,n=2$, we have $z=0,1$ .

But only $z=0$ satisfies the equation $\bar{z}+z^{n}=i(\bar{z}-z^{n})$.

Comment: I think that the answer should be in relation with natural numbers,while we always had that way. By the way,look at the other answer,i came to the same conclusion afterward as that person.